# Vue.js import Array from App.vue in Component

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm facing a problem with importing an Array from the App.vue file to a component. But first I should explain the purpose of this project. There's a component (navigation-drawer) and an App.vue file. The Navigation drawer has vue props in it, which you can dynamically change in the App.vue file. Now, my problem is that the component does not import the array properly. It only shows around 70 or 80 bullet points but it doesn't show the actual content from the array.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation-drawer links= "[ {title='Google' , link='https://www.google.ch' },{ title='Youtube' ,link='https://www.youtube.com' } ]"
    />

    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
  import NavigationDrawer from './components/Navigation-Drawer.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
      NavigationDrawer,
      }
    }
</script>
```

**Navigation-Drawer.vue**

```
<template>
   <div class="navigationdrawer">
    <span @click="openNav" style="fontsize:30px;cursor:pointer;display:flex;justify-content:center;">&#9776;</span>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" @click="closeNav">&times;</a>

        <ul v-for="(link, index) in links" v-bind:key="index">
            <li>{{ link.title }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'NavigationDrawer',
    props: {
        links: Array
 },

 methods: {
     openNav() {
         document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '15%'
         },

    closeNav() {
        document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0%'
        }
    }
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Try `:links="..."` or `v-bind:links="..."`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props. That inline array isn't going to do you any favours either. I'd recommend moving it into App.vue's `data` function.

Comment: You array isn't valid either (this was in another comment but the author deleted it). Like I said, move it to a `data` function, eg `data: () => ({ links: [{ title: 'Google', ... }, ... ] })` and use `:links="links"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As everyone explained you are not passing Array to `NavigationDrawer` component. Currently, you haven't binded Array so it is just string.

TIP: Use [prop validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks) to mitigate this kind of issues

To solve your issue all you have to do is bind it using [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

```js
<navigation-drawer
  :links="[
    {title='Google', link='https://www.google.ch'},
    {title='Youtube', link='https://www.youtube.com'}
  ]"
/>
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, your object syntax is wrong. In js you should using `:` not "=" to declare  property in object.

```js
[ {title='Google' , link='https://www.google.ch' },{ title='Youtube' ,link='https://www.youtube.com' } ]
```

And then you should using v-bind to tell vue `links` it's a JavaScript expression rather than a string.

You can direct declaration links like that.

```
<navigation-drawer
  :links="[{title: 'Google', link: 'https://www.google.ch' }, { title: 'Youtube', link: 'https://www.youtube.com' }]"
/>
```

Also you can use a state to do that.

```
// template
<navigation-drawer :links="links"/>
// script
data() {
  return {
    links: [
      { title: "Google", link: "https://www.google.ch" },
      { title: "Youtube", link: "https://www.youtube.com" }
    ]
  };
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-wave-19evo

Answer (score 0):

Try this below in your App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation-drawer :links="link_array"
    />

    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
  import NavigationDrawer from './components/Navigation-Drawer.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
      NavigationDrawer,
      },
    data(){
      return {
       link_array : "Your Array"   < -----------   
       } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your `link_array` is just as invalid as OP's 

Comment: The whole part of the answer is that he needs to use the array dynamically .